Placing multiple different blocks with a relatively simple fast command
I need to fill an area with 4 different blocks (or more) for a mining sim to work correctly. And it needs to happen almost if not instantaneously with maybe 2 sec of delay.
What ive tried
/fill is definitely not going to cut it as it won't place more than 1 type in all my testing. And there's no gradient command either.
I can't find any commands that help either, (due to Bedrock not allowing scrolling commands) and youtube is useless as well.

Welcome to Arqade! On Minecraft commands questions, please see our guide on what to do before asking a Minecraft commands question, especially the part about “what you’ve tried so far”, and edit in the requested information to your post.

Have you tried using the clone command. Simply build your wanted strip and clone it over when you need it. I'm not that familiar with Bedrock, so I don't know if it works. However, what is "scrolling commands"?

On pc you can use the arows or somthing to go threw the commands to find what you whant
